# Meaning of "Banksy’s your bag"

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context, slang

In the article about [Dismaland](http://www.thisiscolossal.com/2015/08/dismaland/) there is a paragraph saying:

> Inside the walls of a derelict seaside swimming resort in
>   Weston-super-Mare, UK, mysterious construction over the last
>   month—including a dingy looking Disney-like castle and a gargantuan
>   rainbow-colored pinwheel tangled in plastic—suggested something big
>   was afoot. Suspicion and anticipation surrounding the unusual activity
>   attributed to fabled artist and provocateur Banksy has reached a Willy
>   Wonka-esque fervor. Well, if **Banksy’s your bag**, continue
>   fervoring. If not, there’s more than a few reasons to continue
>   reading.

I don't really get the meaning. Does it refer to people buying souvenirs there and stocking them in their bags? I'd be glad for any help.

Answer (score 7):

That use of 'your bag' is a slang sense:

> (not) to be one's bag slang (orig. U.S.): (not) to match one's personal style, taste, or preference; (not) to form part of one's interest, preoccupation, or area of expertise. Usually in negative contexts.

["bag, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/14611?redirectedFrom=your+bag (accessed January 06, 2016).]

The instance you cite is the less common positive use, amounting to

> if Banksy *suits your taste*, continue fervoring.

So far as I can tell, 'fervoring' has nothing to do with buying souvenirs, but rather with something like *sustaining enthusiasm*.